# Insert date array in PostgreSQL table

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2, postgresql-9.3

I have a problem inserting a dynamic array with dates into a table. I'm working with Python 3.3 and using the package psycopg2 to communicate with a Postgres 9.3 database.

I create the table with following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE Test( id serial PRIMARY KEY, listdate DATE[] )
```

En easy example is a list of two dates. Let us assume the list would be `dateList = ['2014-07-07','2014-07-08']`.

Now I want to insert the complete list into the table. If I try the static version:

```
INSERT INTO Test(dateList[1],dateList[2]) VALUES(date '2014-07-07',date '2014-07-08')"
```

the inserting is no problem. But in the reality my list has a dynamic number of dates (at least 100) so the static version is not useful.
I tried different approaches like:

```
INSERT INTO Test VALUES(array" + str(dateList)  +"::date[])
INSERT INTO Test VALUES(array date '" + str(dateList)  +"')
INSERT INTO Test VALUES(date array" + str(dateList)  +")
```

but nothing is successful. Maybe the problem is between the two prefixes `date` and `array`.

Any ideas for a simple SQL statement without an SQL function?

Comment: I found the solution a few minutes after my post by myself. It's `INSERT INTO Test(listdate) VALUES(array" + str(dateList)  +"::date[])`

Answer (score 3):

The other, somewhat simpler option is to use the **string representation** of a date array:

```
INSERT INTO test(listdate)
VALUES ('{2014-07-07,2014-07-08}')
```

You can add an explicit cast, but that's not required:

```
INSERT INTO test(listdate)
VALUES ('{2014-07-07,2014-07-08}'::date[])
```

Your variable would be: `dateList = '{2014-07-07,2014-07-08}'` ..

Comment: @muistooshort: It should. Thank you.